# Java String fragmintation

Tags: java, string, int

I have a string, for example "90 60 90" - body proportions. I want to pull out 3 numbers from the string and put them into int array. 
Like this:

```
sizes[0] = 90;
sizes[1] = 60;
sizes[2] = 90;
```

Perhaps there is more elegant way to solve this problem, but i could come up with only this way. I would be pleased if you could show me more elegant way or help to fix this. Loop stops in this way when j = 2 and a = ' '.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] sizes = {"90 60 90", "90 70 60"};
    //  int[][] firstNumber = new int[sizes.length][3];
        String firstNumber = "";
        String secondNumber = "";
        String thirdNumber = "";
        int spaces = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < sizes.length; i++) {
            int length = sizes[i].length();
            for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
                char a = sizes[j].charAt(j);
                if (a != ' ' && spaces == 0) {
                    firstNumber += String.valueOf(a);
                } else if (a != ' ' && spaces == 1) {
                    secondNumber += String.valueOf(a);
                } else if (a != ' ' && spaces == 2) {
                    thirdNumber += String.valueOf(a);
                } else if (a == ' ') {
                    spaces++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(firstNumber + secondNumber + thirdNumber);
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: `String::split`?

Comment: `int[] array = Stream.of(string.split(" ")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();`

Comment: Looks like it should work. I'll try, thank you. I am a newbie. I tried to search appropriate way, but i couldn't find this simple function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler way than streams is to use a **StringTokenizer**. The argument of its constructor is the String that you want to separate. The method nextToken is called to jump to the next token (in this example from 90 to 60). If there is no argument, tokens are separated by empty space. Here it is:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] sizes = {"90 60 90", "90 70 60"};
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(sizes[0]);
        int[] sizesInt = new int[6];
        sizesInt[0] = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
        sizesInt[1] = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
        sizesInt[2] = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
        st = new StringTokenizer(sizes[1]);
        sizesInt[3] = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
        sizesInt[4] = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
        sizesInt[5] = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());

        System.out.println("sizesInt: " + Arrays.toString(sizesInt));

    }

}
```

Output:

```
sizesInt: [90, 60, 90, 90, 70, 60]
```

Comment: Seems good, because i have not learned that constructions like ArrayList and Streams yet. Thank you.

Comment: You make it way to complex, try to use standard functionallity (`String::split`) as much as possible

Answer (score 3):

You can use :

```
String[] sizes = {"90 60 90", "90 70 60"};
List<Integer[]> list = Stream.of(sizes).map(
        string -> Arrays.asList(string.split("\\s+")).stream()
                .map(s -> Integer.parseInt(s))
                .toArray(Integer[]::new)
).collect(toList());
```

To show the result :

```
list.forEach(array -> System.out.println(Arrays.asList(array)));
```

Outputs

```
[90, 60, 90]
[90, 70, 60]
```

Comment: Instead of `Arrays.asList(sizes).stream()`, you could directly stream the array: `Stream.of(sizes)` or `Arrays.stream(sizes)`

Answer (score 2):

An elegant way would be to use streams. i.e:

to retrieve a `String` array:

```
String[] result = Arrays.stream(sizes)
                        .flatMap((String s) -> Arrays.stream(s.split(" ")))
                        .toArray(String[]::new);
```

to retrieve an `int` array:

```
int[] result = Arrays.stream(sizes)
                     .flatMap((String s) -> Arrays.stream(s.split(" ")))
                     .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                     .toArray();
```

Comment: Then you have everything in one array. Is this the desired outcome?

Comment: @Ward That's what it seems like from the description as far as I can tell and also considering the accepted answer, that clarifies OP wants a single dimensional array.

Comment: @Aominè I find this a bit cleaner.. `Pattern p = Pattern.compile(" ");
        Arrays.stream(sizes)
                .flatMap(p::splitAsStream)
                .toArray(String[]::new);` but it's just about me here

Comment: @Eugene it does indeed seem cleaner and I'll make sure to keep this in mind for future answers. For some unknown reason I am always in the habit of using `s.split(" ")` and not thinking of anything else. Thanks, Eugene, will definitely keep this in mind for situations where it's appropriate.

Comment: @Aominè habits die hard, its not any different for me either

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is:

```
public class StringToArray {

    // we use this as index counter in our lambda (effectively final)
    private static int index = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

     // our String
     String s = "90 60 90";

     // we declare and initialize our int array to store
     // converted Strings to
     int[] array = new int[s.split(" ").length];

        // split by space, get an array, get stream out of 
        // that array, map each String value to int and save
        // to appropriate index in our int array
        Arrays.stream(s.split(" "))
              .map(Integer::parseInt)
              .forEach(x -> array[index++] = x);

        // print out int array content
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach populating a multidimensional array using a single for loop and splitter. Should be efficient. Multidimensional array is intuitive way to hold body proportion information, each row containing cohesive data related to a particular body. Scalable without alteration for as many data rows as required. Tested at [jdoodle](https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler)

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] sizes = {"90 60 90", "90 70 60"};
        String element;
        String[] sizeArray;
        int[][] sizeIntArray= new int[sizes.length][3];

        for (int i = 0; i < sizes.length; i++) {
            element = sizes[i];
            sizeArray=element.split("\\s");
            sizeIntArray[i][0]=Integer.parseInt(sizeArray[0]);
            sizeIntArray[i][1]=Integer.parseInt(sizeArray[1]);
            sizeIntArray[i][2]=Integer.parseInt(sizeArray[2]);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Yevhenii Ivanisenko, this solution gives you the multidimensional array I think you were originally striving for in your post. I deduced this because of the commented out code for mulitdimensional array. This approach is also scalable if required.